# Need an example of a working jUnit test with FirebaseVision - Android studio

Tags: android

I created an app with `FirebaseVision` which run perfect on the device, but when I try to create jUnit I get

`Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process null. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.`

when calling `FirebaseVision.getInstance()`

I tried to add `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` to my test setUp but this causes the test to load for ever.

How do I create a simple jUnit test with FirebaseVision app such as 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android/#3
?

NOTE: I read through other SO posts with a similar error msg, but they refer to running on the device, I have no problem running on the device, this question is specifically about jUnit.

In root level gradle file I have `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'` in `dependencies`

In app/build.gradle file I have  `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` before access firebase object

Better to write in Application class's `onCreate()`

If still issue is there, than check have you added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` at root level gradle file and applied plugin in **app/build.gradle** file at the bottom like `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: As I said in the Post: the code works on the device, the problem is when running jUnit, in such case `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` doesn't make sense since `this` is a junit test, not an app, therefore I pass `context` instead. but this causes the test to get stuck. Please read the Post again - I need an example of a working jUnit